# vector vs list insert performance

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, vector, stl

I just watched a presentation by Herb Sutter (see min. 46 on http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661 )  on various STL containters performance. It looks like `std::vector` is FASTER than a `std::list` even for insertion in the middle, which looks like a big NO-NO first... His explanation was that this is happening because of contiguous memory allocation in a `std::vector`, and because linear transversal seems to be super fast. I am now curious, did anyone observe a visible performance difference between the two in real code? I am not a professional programmer, I just tested a simple example on my laptop and it seems that indeed `std::vector` is inserting faster that a `std::list`. This seems a bit strange though... I would like to understand why the vector is faster in the STL implementation,

Comment: Where exactly are you inserting? If you show us your benchmark program, it will be easier to interpret.

Comment: No, I mean are you inserting at the front of the list? At the back? At a random location? At exactly the middle?

Comment: At `size()/2`, so in the middle, that's why I am puzzled...

Comment: This question is entirely meaningless without details of your platform, compiler, optimisation level, element type...

Comment: It's not meaningless, I reproduced a behaviour pointed out at a C++ conference, and was just curios if some of you saw it in real code... Compiler is `g++4.9`, platform is `debian 7`, computer is a 256 core workstation.

Comment: A significant problem with `std::list` and other node-based containers is poor cache usage. Modern processors have gotten so much faster than memory that badly organized data access can cause the CPU to spend more time waiting than doing useful work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you did not provide a code example, I will provide some possible reasons.

1. `std::list` performs one dynamic memory allocation *per* insert, and dynamic memory allocation is an expensive operation. `std::list` also needs to take O(n/2) time to just **find** the middle element, because it has to follow the pointers instead of just doing one pointer addition.
2. `std::vector` will require shifting all the elements at the end of the list towards the right, which is probably similar or faster than the traversal time for `std::list`.  Moreover, `std::vector` will tend to double in size whenever it runs out of capacity, so it uses only `O(log n)` re-allocations, compared to `O(n)` allocations for `std::list`.

I think you might learn something interesting about the cost of copy vs cost of traversal if you start measuring with a larger size of each container. For example, 20 million elements.

---

Additionally, as  LightnessRacesinOrbit correctly pointed out, `O(1)` just means constant time, while `O(n)` means time proportional to the size of input, but these time bounds do not necessarily translate into practically measured time, especially for small sized inputs, because the `O(1)` time could be hiding a large constant.

However, I believe that for this particular problem, the list traversal is probably the culprit, because it causes `O(n)` time for traversal in order to insert into the middle of the list.

Comment: Ahh ok, I think you're right. The time is spent basically traversing the list, not inserting per se... Because the insertion should be O(1). Thanks! But I think this should be pointed out in C++ books, even the `Josuttis` STL book http://www.cppstdlib.com treats it wrongly.

Comment: @vsoftco: A container with `O(1)` insertion _does not_ automatically mean that it'll be objectively faster to insert an element at position _x_ than a container with `O(n)` insertion, in all cases. Not at all. Algorithmic complexity is about the _growth_ of calculation time with respect to _n_, not about absolute comparisons. Your constant time complexity won't help you much if the constant factor is 3 hours.

Comment: @merlin2011: Talking to the OP

Comment: Yes I understand, I know constants can make a huge difference in big O notation, I was not trying to be pedantic but was just curios if using a `std::vector` seems to be better than using a `std::list`, at least for small number of elements.

Comment: @vsoftco: It's not just about the number of elements, is what I'm saying. There are other factors. Shifting a few `int`s is easy, so here you're seeing it as faster than dynamic allocation. Shifting a few `std::map<X,Y>` (which themselves have a ton of elements) will not be. So your generalisation is misleading :)

Comment: Ok, I understand, and basically this was my question. Did you see a different behaviour in real code? I.e., using a container with BIG objects? Herb was somehow saying that vector seems to be faster.

Comment: @vsoftco: With large element types, it simply won't be faster.

Comment: Why not? If the elements are guaranteed to be in contiguous memory (as std::vector guarantees), then aren't you basically just doing a `memcpy`, isn't it so? There is no need for copy/construction etc, at least this is what I think, but that's why I asked the question, 'cause you guys may know better :)

Comment: @vsoftco, The best way to answer these kinds of performance questions is to write more benchmarks.

Comment: @vsoftco, When you have large objects, the cost of `std::list` traversal remains the same (following pointers), but the cost of `memcpy` increases simply because you are copying more memory for the same number of objects.

Comment: @vsoftco, The question of how large your objects have to be before that boundary is crossed is system-dependent.

Comment: Ok, so I guess that "there exists an N(that depends on the size of the object stored in the container) for which list becomes better" Thanks!

Comment: @vsoftco, At which point you would probably want to switch to storing object pointers instead of objects in your `std::vector`. :)

Comment: I am doing this already :) This was just a kind of "why the heck is this happening" question :)

Comment: @vsoftco, Also, please mark this answer as the accepted answer, if it resolved your question.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mark it, did it now :)